# python: компиляция проекта (PyCharm)

Tags: python, python-3.x, компиляция, pycharm

Подскажите, есть ли возможность компилировать (чтобы код быстрее работал) проекты. И если есть, то возможно ли это сделать через PyCharm?

Очень не хочется тратить время на переписывание кода на C++, но питоновский работает неприемлемо медленно (генерируется данные по времени и скорость генерации где-то 1 секунда за 1 минуту, а хотелось бы на порядок побыстрее)

Comment: Возможности компиляции в обычном смысле нет. Можно пробовать оптимизировать сам алгоритм, прикручивать jit, пробовать переписывать с помощью cython.

Comment: Надо смотреть что там генерится, что за данные. Возможно, для них уже написана библиотека для питона на с++. А это обычно лучший способ ускорить код на питоне. Ну и конечно мультипоточность, кэширование, numba и т.д.

Comment: @CrazyElf, возможно - генерируются случайные числа по заданному дискретному распределению, т.е. у меня есть ПВР (предельное распределение вероятностей) и мне надо нагенерировать несколько миллионов чисел по нему, я использую пока самый медленный из возможных способов (в цикле получаю 2 случайных числа и если они не удовлетворяют ПВР делаю еще раз цикл, понятно что это очень долго :()

Comment: @Zhihar А тут ничего подходящего нет? Хотя для этого надо знать, как называется нужное распределение https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/stats/discrete.html

Comment: @Zhihar Вы лучше задайте новый вопрос по сути - насчёт вероятностей и т.д. У нас же тут есть как минимум 2-3 человека, очень хорошо понимающих в статистике, я думаю, они разберутся, что же вам нужно. В статистических пакетах наверняка есть всё необходимое, просто нужен человек, который сопоставит пакеты с хотелками. А для этого нужен правильный вопрос именно про статистику, в этот не факт что они заглянут. Статистическими пакетами всё это моментально наверное делается.

Answer (score 0):

Можешь взглянуть в сторону [Cython](https://cython.org). Врядли PyCharm сможет тебе помочь.

А также для ускорения питона можешь использовать [альтернативный интерпретатор - PyPy](https://www.pypy.org).